# Ruby nested hash 'super' key access

Tags: ruby, recursion, hash, nested

Imagine we've got nested hash like this:

```
{Class=>{"attr"=>{NestedClass=>{"nested_attr"=>9}}}}
```

I work with recursive method that brings me to that point:

```
{Class=>{"attr"=>{NestedClass=>{"nested_attr"=>9}}}}
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

where `NestedClass` is key, and `{"nested_attr"=>9}}}}` is a value.

Now, I would like to modify to change hash `{NestedClass=>{"nested_attr"=>9}}}}` to some object, but it needs to be like

```
{Class=>{"attr"=>some_new_object}}
```

How can achieve such result?

Here is sample method I am using:

```
def drill(hash)
  hash.each do |key, value|
    drill(value) if value.instance_of?(Hash)
    build_partial(key, value) if class?(key)
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok, so actually I managed to figure this out. I had to add hash[key] = drill(value) and return build_partial(key,value).

Comment: Glad you figured it out -- if you feel like you have the answer, post it and mark it as solved (you will have to wait two days) so others can find it faster in the future.

Comment: Ok, I'll do this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after few moments I posted this I found out how it might work. Here is the code:

```
def drill(hash)
  hash.each do |key, value|
    hash[key] = drill(value) if value.instance_of?(Hash)
    return build_partial(key, value) if class?(key)
  end
end
```

I hope it will help someone with similar problem.